# How to use xmlhttp request on chrome packaged app

Tags: google-chrome-app

When I try use xmlhttprequest I get this error please let me know how to solve it.

> "because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' ". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set,
>   so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

```
                    var xmlhttp =   new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
           var resp     =   xmlhttp.responseText;   

            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("POST",myserviceURL,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

Note : I added that URL on manifest permission list .

Regards
Chandru.

Comment: Have you defined a `content_security_policy` in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have specified permission to access your service URL in your manifest file. You need to list each URL that you want to access.

Take a look at our GDrive sample in the chrome-app-samples on Github.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples